# How can I specify the type of the "this" value for a closure in JetBrains IDEs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, phpstorm, webstorm

JetBrains has an old blog post about JSDoc annotations that explains how to inform the IDE of variable types http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/10/validating-javascript-code-with-jsdoc-types-annotations/.

I still, however, cannot seem to find a way to tell the IDE that the "this" value in many jQuery callbacks are HTMLElements. For example:

```
/**
 * Enable input
 * @returns {SomeConstructor}
 */
SomeConstructor.prototype.enableInput = function(){
    this.$markup.find('input').each(function(){
        this.disabled = false;
    });
    return this;
};
```

The above example will still produce a warning in the IDE - "Potentially invalid usage of this".

[image]
How can I specify that "this" refers to a HTMLElement object?

EDIT:

After looking through the JSDoc documentation I found the @this annotation http://usejsdoc.org/tags-this.html. @this will allow you to specify a "this" value for an entire function, but in the posted example the IDE will think it's returning an HTMLElement rather than a SomeConstructor.

Comment: So you are using phpstorm or webstorm?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but... the signature of the callback to jQuery's each function is effectively `Function( Integer index, Element element )`, where `element === this`, so you could maybe declare the arguments and annotate the type of the second one?

Comment: Using PHPStorm, but the question applies to both. Yes, that is one approach @BenGriffiths, but it also applies to things like $(element).on('click', function(){ //some code}) as well :/.

Comment: "Potentially invalid usage of this" won't be highlighted for this case in WebStorm/PhpStorm 2016.2. For now, I may only suggest to annotate inner   function expression like this
`this.$markup.find('input').each(/** @this {HTMLElement} */ function(){});`

Comment: @de1mar You should post this as an answer - it works! I had tried this same method several times, but put my comments inside the function(/**@this {HTMLElement}*/), so it didn't work. Really puts my mind at ease to watch all of those squiggly lines disappear :).

Answer (score 2):

@de1mar in the comments nailed it. The trick is to place /**@this {HTMLElement} just before the closure. So, for example:

```
/**
 * Enable input
 * @returns {SomeConstructor}
 */
SomeConstructor.prototype.enableInput = function(){
    this.$markup.find('input').each(/**@this {HTMLElement}*/function(){
        this.disabled = false;
    });
    return this;
};
```

Or,

```
SomeConstructor.prototype.listenForCheck = function(){
    this.$markup.find('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', /**@this {HTMLInputElement}*/ function(){
        //Do something
    });
};
```

Should be useful for anyone out there writing jQuery in a jetbrains IDE. Thanks @del1mar!